# Can units retreat over the sea?

Tags: game-of-thrones

While playing Game of Thrones, the Lannisters attacked the Greyjoys at Riverrun.

The Greyjoys were defeated and attempted to retreat over Ironman's Bay via ship. Is this allowed, or must retreats be made over land?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A genuine question to the close voters: what is unclear about this question? I'm not a GoT expert, but this (once the objectionable formatting was cleaned up) looks to me at first glance to be a reasonable, well scoped quesion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [official rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/30/4f/304f72e3-4fe4-4f91-bfbe-75133161b092/va65_agot2_rulebook_web.pdf) allow it:

> A player is allowed to use ship transport to retreat his
> units.

[image]